# System is taking up too much CPU Power

Tags: cpu, process, cpu-usage, process-explorer

The "System" is taking up too much CPU usage. I've had this problem for a while but it keeps getting worse, I feel. Sometimes I need to restart the computer multiple times until I'm lucky and it won't go so high.

Screenshot of Process Explorer and the System process's threads:

[image]

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), stop ProcessExplorer (**important**), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Captue 1 minute of the CPU usage, now click on **Save** to save the data into a ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: I'm having troubles installing the program. edit: I've successfully installed it :)

Comment: ok, you can also upload the zip to my dropbox directly: https://www.dropbox.com/request/ioUxrVRNDzPFWZpanxOr

Comment: Currently my PC is running fine, but next time I reboot it I expect it to fail, so it may be a while until I upload the trace, also dealing with a few things at home.

Comment: have you ever seen the issue again? Or can we close it as "can't repro the issue"